# Какие есть способы запуска из программы на C программ на других языках в Linux?

Tags: linux, c

Какие есть способы запуска из программы на C программ на других языках в Linux? Программой считается любая линейная программа, закодированная на любых языках программирования. Размещена она может быть где угодно.

Comment: Код на ассемблере нельзя запускать из Си. Можно скомпилировать ассемблерный код в объектный файл и слинковать со скомпилированным в объектный файл кодом на Си. Таким способом можно взаимодействовать практически с любым компилируемым языком. Это очень разные способы взаимодействия по сравнению с вызовом кода Lua - для Lua из сишного кода идет обращение к интрепретатору (прилинкованному статически или в виде динамической библиотеки), а интерпретатор уже запускает код на Lua. Так можно взаимодействовать со многими интерпретируемыми языками, например с Python.

Comment: @insolor, имелись в виду ассемблерных вставки.

Comment: на любых. см `system()`

Comment: Ассемблерная вставка не есть запуск кола на асме из кода на Си. Он будет скомпилирован вместе с сишным кодом в единое целое и все.

Comment: А почему закрыли вопрос?

Comment: @insolor, именно это и есть то, о чём я спросил.

Comment: @Грузчик, в плашке о закрытии есть полезная ссылка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код на других языках можно запускать разными способами.

1. Вставка в непосредственно кода на другом языке, поддерживаемом тем же компилятором. Как правило, прокатывает только с Asm.
2. Статическая линковка с объектными файлами или либами, созданными совместимым компилятором. Большинство компилируемых языков могут использовать линковку с либами на Asm, C и C++. Вроде бы ещё все языки, поддерживаемые компилятором LLVM можно линковать между собой, но не уверен.
3. Динамическая линковка с разделяемыми библиотеками (dll в windows и so в linux). Можно линковаться со всеми языками, которые поддерживают создание таких библиотек. А это почти все компилируемые.
4. Встраивание в свой язык интерпретатора другого языка. Сам интерпретатор может быть написан на том же языке, или подключен одним из вышеописанных способов. Так делается с упомянутым Lua.
5. Запуск отдельной программы на другом языке и кросспроцессное взаимодействие с ней любым способом. AlexGlebe упомянул о простейшем из них, когда взаимодействие состоит просто в факте запуск.

Comment: Единственный полный и адекватный ответ.